# VS Code setup to mimic VS debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, react-redux

I am involved in an ASP.NET MVC application that uses React/Redux. Using VS I can bring up the solution set the default project and with F5 debug the application. The default application just so happens to be a web application so in debugging VS starts IISExpress and I can set breakpoints in the C# code. 
I would like to setup VS Code to debug the client side code. For example there are a number of React components defined using .tsx. I would like to set a break point in the .tsx code without having to resort to using the Chrome debugging tools and find the corresponding js code. Is this possible? What do I have to do to launch.json (and possibly other steps) to allow debugging this app with VS Code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug

it allows you to add breakpoints to javascript , and then debug directly from chrome without running external debugging tools.

Comment: How do I control symbol generation so I can set a breakpoint in Typescript or .tsx?

Comment: This is good information but there seems to need to be a client and server launch.json that makes this work. The server is a ASP.NET MVC application with controllers and views. The client is basically standard JavaScipt, HTML, and React. At present from what I have read so far I need to start up the server, startup a debugger for the server (this would be the debugger for MVC), and startup a debugger for the client code. The last two steps seem to involve some "magic" launch.json" profiles that I have not grasped yet. The first?